# Array adapter modified in background exception

Tags: android, multithreading, android-listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

in my app i have a background model (sort of DB) that is constantly being updated from my server.
my problem is that i have various adapters which update their data according to this model.
each time the model is updated i send a broadcast to the activities so they notify the adapters (notifyDataSetChanged).
90% of the time this works perfectly, the other 10%  - usually when the UI thread is working very hard (onActivityResume of instance) , when the thread has a lot of UI to update - i get the following error:

"Thread: main, Exception: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. ..... Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread."

my question is: what is best practice for working with adapters and maintaining some kind of DB that needs to be updated from a background thread?

10x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you're calling `notifyDataSetChanged` from the UI thread.
2. Make sure you're updating the content of the adapter from the UI thread only.

You can use the UI `Handler` thread and its message queue in order to post updates to the data model using the UI thread from other background threads. More details here [Android Handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Comment: yes, i know this. but i do not want to duplicate my DB so the adapter will only be updated from UI thread

Comment: ok. this looks like it might solve my problem. i will check this out. 10x!